# javascript refresh page 5 seconds after form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

The form I am working with is an embedded js form, so I don't have direct access to the code.

I am at a tradeshow, and I want the page with the form to refresh 5 seconds after the form has been submitted.

I am using this code, but not getting a refresh. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Reload page 5 seconds after form submission
$("form").onsubmit = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = "/tradeshow/"; 
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The actual embedded form code is this:
    <script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    css: '',
    portalId: '2560825',
    formId: '941427cd-9225-4192-aa74-c8f24eb64e7d'
  });
</script>

Comment: That code doesn't make sense as well as you don't show where you use it Provide a proper and complete explanation for the expected behavior. If the form submits through default submit process issue is even more complex since a page reload will occur as part of submit

Comment: Once the form is submitted the new page is loaded unless you handle the submission asynchronously. You should pass some query parameter to the target page and add `setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 5000);` there

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the [`location.reload()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) for this.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Reload page 5 seconds after form submission
$("form").onsubmit = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload(true); //MODIFICATION
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: The setTimeout code will be evaluated on page load unless it would fail because of jQuery not initialized

Comment: I am unable to understand, could you please explain the previous comment, @AlexanderM.

Comment: This modified code doesn't do anything -- the page does not refresh.

Comment: Here is the entire code -- it is on a Wordpress page:

Comment: <div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin:0 auto;">
<!-- [if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({ 
    css: '',
    portalId: '2560825',
    formId: '941427cd-9225-4192-aa74-c8f24eb64e7d'
  });
</script>
</div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
// Reload page 5 seconds after form submission
$("form").onsubmit = setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload(true); //MODIFICATION
    }, 5000);
</script>

Answer (score -2):

You can only meta tag to update user page without submiting form:

```
meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0.5"
```